Blocking with Strange Wait Resource
My shop had two significant blocking storms yesterday with most of the blocking victims piling up behind Drop table commands in a user database for short life processing tables (coding practice that is under review).
This wait resource has surprisingly few online references.    I haven’t seen this one before.
WaitText
LCK_M_SCH_M 

WaitResource
METADATA: database_id = 18
ALL_AUDIT_SPECIFICATIONS_AND_ACTIONS(database_id = 18), lockPartitionId = 0

Any insights or resources on this wait resource would be appreciated.

Audit scripts:
/****** Object:  Audit [DatabasePermissionsAudit]    Script Date: 12/18/2024 3:30:13 PM ******/

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [name1]

TO FILE

(              FILEPATH = N'C:\mypath\DatabaseAuditLogs\'

               ,MAXSIZE = 500 MB

               ,MAX_FILES = 5

               ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF

) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE, AUDIT_GUID = 'b6c33b5a-93a0-419f-ad33-d0d12ce73f62')
USE [master]

GO

 

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Name1]

FOR SERVER AUDIT [Name1]

ADD (DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP),

ADD (DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP),

ADD (DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP)

WITH (STATE = ON)

GO

 

 

USE [master]

GO

 



ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Name1] WITH (STATE = ON)

GO

 

 

/****** Object:  Audit [ServerPermissionsAudit]    Script Date: 12/18/2024 3:30:55 PM ******/

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Name2]

TO FILE

(              FILEPATH = N'C:\mypath\ServerAuditLogs\'

               ,MAXSIZE = 500 MB

               ,MAX_FILES = 5

               ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF

) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE, AUDIT_GUID = '966a14e5-6efe-4085-87af-3f48d61b5dad')

ALTER SERVER AUDIT [name2] WITH (STATE = ON)
CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Name2]

FOR SERVER AUDIT [Name2]

ADD (SERVER_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP),

ADD (SERVER_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP)

WITH (STATE = ON)

GO

GO


The wait type unfortunately isn't documented. Feel encouraged to upvote my request to document it here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/4a378000-82bd-ef11-95f5-000d3a7d9e49
